# How can i get STS to resolve thy path to the web.xml i defined in a maven profile?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-tool-suite

I have a maven project that has different environments for development and production. There are some parts in the web.xml that need to be removed for production. Until today, there was a antrunner based xml task that did exactly that. Now i want to remove the scripting-part and introduce 2 versions of the web.xml. Basically, i would extend the path "WEB-INF/web.xml" to "WEB-INF/dev/web.xml". This was configured in both profiles:

```
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <webxml.path>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dev/WEB.xml</webxml.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Same for the other profile, just with a different path.

Later, I will use the maven-war-plugin to make sure maven finds the file:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-war</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>war</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</warSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>${webxml.path}</webXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

And everything works fine, but just as long as I build from the commandline.
I told the Spring Tool Suite 3.7 to update with the dev profile,[sadly it somehow refuses to resolve that path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apxRd.png).

When I use the "create Descriptor-Stub" from the context menu, it even creates a file called ${webxml.path} with default web.xml content.

The provided error message is:

> web.xml is missing and failOnMissingWebXml is set to true

I dont want to disable that check (failOnMissingWebXml) if possible.

Is there any way to get STS to be a bit more eager on resolving variables?

Update:
While writing this, I found out, that it is possible to use the maven-resources plugin to copy the file manually to the respective path when building from the IDE. It would be great to get m2e to respect the  attribute from the war-plugin. Or is this simply not possible? Is the buildprocess not executed by maven itself, even though i explicitly specified the external version?

Comment: I would love to help, but this sounds more like a question for the m2e and m2e-wtp tooling in Eclipse/STS, so maybe the forums that they have might help as well: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/245/

Comment: Okay, i will ask around over there aswell. Thanks for the pointer!